# How was this simplification done?

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial, euler-maclaurin

> \begin{align*} \begin{pmatrix}
>      -2\\
>      n\end{pmatrix}&=\frac{(-2)(-3)(-4)\dots(-2-n+1)}{n!}\\[5pt] &= (-1)^n\frac{2\times3\times4\times\dots n(n+1)}{n!}\\[5pt]  
>  &=(-1)^n(n+1)\\[5pt] \end{align*}

While reviewing the binomial theorem, I came across this example problem and I feel like this simplification was not clearly explained. It seems like -1 was factored out but what happens to the expression it is multiplied by. How is it written in such a way? Also, why is $-1$ raised to the power of $n$...$(-1)^n$. I do not find this intuitive and felt like a step was skipped although that might not be the case.

Overall, I just want to understand what the process is here.

Comment: $-1$ is factored out $n$ times (from each term $-2$, $-3$, $-4$, ..., $-(n+1)$)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner In the second line, middle expression, how is there a $n(n+1)$.

Comment: $(-2)(-3)(-4)=(-1\times2)(-1\times3)(-1\times4)=(-1)(2)(-1)(3)(-1)(4)=(-1)^3(2)(3)(4)$.

Comment: $-2-n+1=-n-1=-(n+1)$

Comment: The $n(n+1)$ would be more clearly written as $n\times(n+1)$. It's the last *two* parts of the numerator. Notice that $(-2-n+1)=(-1)(n+1)$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner And the $n$ being multiplied by $n+1$? Where does the $n$ come from? Thanks.

Comment: The $n$ comes from the sequence $2,3,4,\dots,n,n+1$.

Comment: @Karl Yes, that's understood, but why is there an $n$ anyway?

Comment: @cpt:  as Karl wrote; every integer from $-2$ to $-(n+1)$ is included

Comment: Oh, okay! Yeah, the sequence. A lot to take into account and think about while solving this. At least for me.

When $-1$ is factored out it is also easier to see. Alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I like using the product notation
so everything is explicit.

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{-2}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-2-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2+k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=2}^{n+1} k}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} k}{n!}
\qquad\text{(adds the term with } k=1)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{n!}\\
&=(-1)^n(n+1)\\
\end{array}
$

More generally,
if $m$ is a positive integer,

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{-m}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (-m-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (m+k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=m}^{n+m-1} k}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=1}^{n+m-1} k}{n!\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}k}
\qquad\text{(adds the term with } k=1 \text{ to } m-1)\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n(n+m-1)!}{n!(m-1)!}\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Why did you decide to add the term $1$ so that $k=1$?

Comment: So it coulde be a full factorial from 1 to n+1.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m>n$. We can write simplify
$$\dbinom mn=\dfrac{m!}{n!\,(m-n)!}=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-n+1)}{n!}.$$

By analogy, if $m<n$, we can set
$$\dbinom mn=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)\dots(m-n+1)}{n!}.$$
In particular, if $m<0$, the numerator has all its factors negative, so we can write it  as \begin{align}&-|m|\cdot -\bigl(|m|+1\bigr)\cdot -\bigl(|m|+2\bigr)\dots -\bigl(|m|+n-1\bigr)=\\[1ex]
&(-1)^n|m|\bigl(|m|+1\bigr)\bigl(|m|+2\bigr)\dots\bigl(|m|+n-1\bigr)
\end{align}
since there are $n$ factors.

Comment: It's not just by analogy. For any complex $c$ and positive integer $n$, $\binom{c}{n}$ is defined as $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(c-k)/n!$.

Comment: I know. I mean the justification of this definition is just an analogy.